# Please help me translate this sentence

Tags: translation

What does it means? And please explain to me every words meaning and every particles used in this :
어쩐지, 좋은 느낌이 드는 여자야. 약간 그리운 느낌도 들고.

Comment: where did you find this and what have you tried in translating this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm native Korean (English is not my mother tongue) and I'm not sure my translation is correct in English, but here's my translation :

> Somehow, she feels good. And I think I somewhat miss her.

`어쩐지` means `No matter`, or `Somehow`. Like, if just saying `어쩐지.` than it means like `I knew it.`. But I think `어쩐지` in given sentence is more like `somehow`. 
 According to 표준국어대사전(Standard Korean Dictionary), it means `어찌 된 까닭인지`(it's like `somehow` at the beginning of the sentence.)

> 어쩐지 불안하다 : Somehow I feel insecure/Somehow it's nervous
>
> 어쩐지 불안하더라 : No matter why I felt insecure/No matter why I was nervous

`좋은` is from `좋다`, means `good`. Yup, that's all.

`느낌이` is `느낌` + `이`, and `이` is postposition(관사) makes noun as subject. `느낌` is `feeling`.

`든다` usually used with `느낌`, and `느낌이 들다` is `feels`.

> 안좋은 느낌이 든다 : It feels bad/It doesn't feel good

`약간` is `little bit`.

`그리운` is from `그립다`, means something like 'feeling of missing someone/something'.

`느낌도` is `느낌` + `도`, `도` is postposition(관사) that make noun as subject PLUS adding meaning of 'additionally` to the noun.

`들고` is from `들다`, too. Ending sentence with `고` is like ending sentence with `, too`.

Answer (score 0):

어쩐지, 좋은 느낌이 드는 여자야. 약간 그리운 느낌도 들고.
I don’t know why, but she gives me good vibes, and also a sentiment of good old days a little bit.